# nav-pills is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The below code is not working in IE 8.0
It works fine in firefox and chrome browsers . In IE the list items instead of coming on a single row they are coming in multiple lines. How to address this.

I am using Bootstrap v2.0.0
and jQuery v1.7.1

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">

                    <li>
                        <a  href="#" data-toggle="pill">openorder" 
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                        <a  href="#" data-toggle="pill">completedorder</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a  href="#" data-toggle="pill">service" </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say with only the HTML here and no example.  You tagged this with `javascript` and `jquery` - is there some kind of problem here too?

I think you should remove the `pull-left` class because that just makes the times inside float to the left.  I suspect this is your problem.

Comment: Well, I put your code into an example and it seems to be working just fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE.  http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/YtgUa/